# Mobx passing callback to update progress not letting me update observable in real time

Tags: observable, mobx, mobx-react

I have a function to put an object in firebase storage. This function takes a callback that gives me the progress back so that i can track it. I would like to store this progress in an observable however when I try to update the observable via a callback I am getting errors that my observable is undefined. Heres a stripped example:

```
function putThingInFirebase(thing, cb) {
  // ...
  const videoUploadTask = videoStorageRef.put(thing)
  videoUploadTask.on('state_changed', snap => {
  let progress = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
  cb(Math.round(progress)) // callback from my store
  // handle errors and such
  // ....


// my store
class store {
  @observable progress
  @action upload(thing) {
     putThingInFirebase(thing, this.progressCB)
        .then(...)
  }
  progressCB(x) { // ive tried @action and @action.bound
    this.progress = x // here i get errors that this.progress is undefined yet when i do a console.log, x is being updated as expected
  }
}
```

What I expect to happen is the observable to be updated via the callback.
What I am getting is this.progress is undefined.

My question is this: What is the correct way to update this observable so that i can monitor the progress of the upload?

Thank you guys for your time and help!

EDIT: Joel was correct. See my comments below for the true culprit though!

As far as the suggestion about using the resolution from the promise, unfortunately I needed to have access to the ‘state_changed’ listener which wouldn’t be possible in the .then().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing your context of `this`

when you call `cb()` `progressCB()` is called but in this function `this` is not the store instance.

try:

```
putThingInFirebase(thing, this.progressCB.bind(this));

//or
putThingInFirebase(thing, (x) => this.progressCB(x));
```

### extra advise

Since you return a promise `.then()` why not put this method in there? instead of *also* adding a callback function?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up refactoring s bunch of stuff but I’ll see if that was in fact my problem... I thought the context was my problem initially but I was using a bound action (maybe I misunderstood what a bound action was) and I still got the error. When I try again I’ll use an arrow function so it’s bound for sure. I’ll for sure mark your answer as correct once I get back in that codebase and check. Thanks again! Total noob mistake if that’s what it is! Lol

Comment: @acount.bound is fine, it does what it says. although i think it's still advised to bind yourself: `progressCB(x) {` to `progressCB = (x) => {` and its fixed.

Comment: I just figured out why @action.bound wasn’t working for me!  With my dev tools open it shrank my viewport and hid my component, thus, making me think it wasn’t working... it was in fact working the whole time! You were very much correct though with the context... in my example I had removed the bound action because I was trying different things...